# How to split things up in a grape api app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, grape-api

In every examples I see, people only implement one giant api.rb file. Ex:

- [intridea/grape](https://github.com/intridea/grape)
- [bloudraak/grape-sample-blog-api](https://github.com/bloudraak/grape-sample-blog-api/blob/master/app/api/blog/api.rb)
- [djones/grape-goliath-example](https://github.com/djones/grape-goliath-example/blob/master/app/apis/posts.rb)

While this approach works fine as is, it can quickly become crowded and difficult to maintain so I would like to split things up on my app.

For instance, I would like to split my entities from my resources, and then split up my resources between different files. For examples:

```
app
 - api
   api.rb
   - entities
     - weblog.rb
     - post.rb
     - comment.rb
   - resources
     - weblog.rb
     - post.rb
     - comment.rb
```

Now, **api.rb** would be something like:

```ruby
require 'grape'
module Blog
  class API < Grape::API
    prefix "api"
  end
end
```

**app/api/entities/post.rb** would be something like:

```ruby
module Blog
  module Entities
    class Post < Grape::Entity
      root 'posts', 'posts'
      expose :id
      expose :content
    end
  end
end
```

**app/api/resources/post.rb** would be something like:

```ruby
module Blog
  class API < Grape::API
    resource :posts do
      get do
        present Post.all, with: Blog::Entities::Post
      end

      desc "returns the payment method corresponding to a certain id"
      params do
        requires :id, :type => Integer, :desc => "Post id."
      end
      get ':id' do
        present Post.find(params[:id]), with: Blog::Entities::Post
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When we do this, we encounter the following message:

> Expected /blog-app/api/resources/post.rb to define Post

---

**SOLUTION (thanks to dB. and my co-workers)**

You have to change the structure to something like:

```
app
 - api
   api.rb
   - resources
     - post_api.rb
```

Then, in the **post_api.rb**

```
module Blog
  class Resources::PostAPI < Grape::API
    resource :posts do
      get do
        present Post.all
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Finally, the **api.rb** becomes:

```ruby
require 'grape'
module Blog
  class API < Grape::API
    prefix 'api'
    version 'v1', :using => :path
    format :json

    mount Blog::Resources::PostAPI => '/'
  end
end
```

Now `/api/v1/posts` should work :)

Comment: What would happened if I had another version of API - v2 and I would want to expose different name of attribute content, so let's say I would have ```expose :body``` instead of ```expose :content``` meanwhile I will still have to have support for v1. I think I will start putting Entities into version folder, am I right? Or how would you handle that in this setup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The class in post.rb should be Post, not API. Then you can mount the Post API inside class API.

```
class API < Grape::API
  mount Blog::Post => '/'
end
```

To avoid confusion I would put Post in a Resources namespace, too or rename it to PostAPI.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dB. In fact you have to namespace AND rename for rails to not get confused... works now!

Comment: Note that you should be able to omit the right hand side of `mount`, so just `mount Blog::Resources::PostAPI` should work, no need to mount on `/`.

Answer (score 1):

I found it not working for path prefix:

```
mount Blog::Post => '/blog'
```

doesn't work if you want have prefix the path.

use

```
namespace :blog do
   mount Blog::Post
end
```

Hope it helps!