# Split Grape API (non-Rails) into different files

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-grape, grape-api

I am writing an API in Grape, but it stands alone, with no Rails or Sinatra or anything. I'd like to split the `app.rb` file into separate files. I have looked at [How to split things up in a grape api app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857987/how-to-split-things-up-in-a-grape-api-app), but that is with Rails.

I'm not sure how to make this work with modules or classes — I did try subclassing the different files into my big `GrapeApp`, but that was ugly and I'm not even sure it worked properly. What's the best way to do this?

I currently have versions split by folders (`v1`, `v2`, etc) but that is all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to subclass from your main app, you can just mount separate Grape::API sub-classes inside the main one. And of course you can define those classes in separate files, and use `require` to load in all the routes, entities and helpers that you app might need. I have found it useful to create one mini-app per "domain object", and load those in `app.rb`, which looks like this:

```
  # I put the big list of requires in another file . . 
  require 'base_requires'

  class MyApp < Grape::API
    prefix      'api'
    version     'v2'
    format      :json

    # Helpers are modules which can have their own files of course
    helpers APIAuthorisation

    # Each of these routes deals with a particular sort of API object
    group( :foo ) { mount APIRoutes::Foo }
    group( :bar ) { mount APIRoutes::Bar }
  end
```

I arrange files in folders, fairly arbitrarily:

```
# Each file here defines a subclass of Grape::API
/routes/foo.rb 

# Each file here defines a subclass of Grape::Entity
/entities/foo.rb

# Files here marshal together functions from gems, the model and elsewhere for easy use
/helpers/authorise.rb
```

I would probably emulate Rails and have a `/models/` folder or similar to hold ActiveRecord or DataMapper definitions, but as it happens that is provided for me in a different pattern in my current project.

Most of my routes look very basic, they just call a relevant helper method, then present an entity based on it. E.g. `/routes/foo.rb` might look like this:

```
module APIRoutes
  class Foo < Grape::API
    helpers APIFooHelpers

    get :all do
      present get_all_users_foos, :with => APIEntity::Foo
    end

    group "id/:id" do
      before do
        @foo = Model::Foo.first( :id => params[:id] )
        error_if_cannot_access! @foo
      end

      get do
        present @foo, :with => APIEntity::Foo, :type => :full
      end

      put do
        update_foo( @foo, params )
        present @foo, :with => APIEntity::Foo, :type => :full
      end

      delete do
        delete_foo @foo
        true
      end
    end # group "id/:id"
  end # class Foo
end # module APIRoutes
```

Comment: Do each of these `routes` files `require` grape?

Comment: @tekknolgi: You should `require 'grape'` before defining the `Grape::API` subclasses, but that could be in the main `app.rb` if you don't want to repeat it everywhere.

Comment: Ok and it won't error out because of undefined variables and classes and stuff?

Comment: @tekknolgi: It shouldn't, but I cannot predict everything you need to do. If you end up with a structure that isn't working for some reason, it may be worth asking another SO question. Most problems with requires are just a matter of getting them in the right order.

Comment: Alright sounds good. I will give it a shot! You're everywhere on my Ruby questions — thanks!